# how to compare array.include(arrayData) in vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

i have two array data

```
checked: [
'orange', 'apple', 'juice'
]
```

and 2nd

```
products: [
 '0': {
    title: 'this is product title',
    categories: [
     'apple', 'juice'
    ]
  }
]
```

i want to to filter data with computed property with checkbox

i tried this

```
computed: {
   filterProducts(){
       return this.products.filter(product => this.checked.includes(product.categories));
   }
}
```

but its not working how can i do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for that.

Here is an example:

```js
checked = [
  'orange', 'apple', 'juice'
]

products = [{
  title: 'this is product title',
  categories: [
    'apple', 'juice'
  ]
}];

const filteredProducts = products.filter(({ categories }) => categories.every(cat => checked.includes(cat)));

console.log(filteredProducts);
```

This will return an array of products that have a `categories` array with all its values included in the `checked` array.

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're trying to do, if you instead want to get all the products with a `categories` array that has at least one of its values in the `checked` array, use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of `.every()`.

Comment: may i know if checked data is empty and i want still want to show all products how?

Comment: @sidheart You can skip the filtering if the `checked` array is empty, something like `const filteredProducts = !checked.length ? products : products.filter.....`.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to check if an array of strings includes an array (which won't work even if your initial array contained arrays). Instead of using `.includes()`, use [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) on `product.categories` to check if all items within this array are contained within checked:

```js
const checked = ['orange', 'apple', 'juice'];

const products = [
  {
    title: 'this is product title',
    categories: ['apple', 'juice']
  }
];

const computed = products.filter(product => product.categories.every(item => checked.includes(item) || !checked.length));

console.log(computed);
```

Comment: thank its working but may i know if checked data is empty and i want still want to show all products how?

Comment: @sidheart you can add `|| !checked.length` in the `.every()` predicate. I've updated my answer